# Django QuerySet with filtered related objects

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
class Quarter(models.Model):
    ...


class House(models.Model):
    quarter = models.ForeignKey(Quarter, related_name='houses')


class FloorRange(models.Model):
    house = models.ForeignKey(House, related_name='floor_ranges')
    is_commercial = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Help me find the best way to get `houses` of `Quarter` object, where `houses` have one or more `floor_ranges` with `is_commercial=True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get all the houses related to a quarter.

```
houses = House.objects.filter(quarter=quarter)
```

Then filter the result to those with at least one floor range with `is_commercial=True`. To do this, use the related name `floor_ranges`, and the double underscore `__` to span the relation.

```
houses = houses.filter(floor_ranges__is_commercial=True)
```

Finally, use `distinct()` to prevent duplicate results for houses with multiple floor ranges with `is_commercial=True`.

```
houses = houses.distinct()
```

Comment: Thank you, and i think in one line it better: House.objects.filter(quarter=quarter, floor_ranges__is_commercial=False).distinct()

Comment: Sure, I split it into multiple lines to make it easier to explain.